# For loop inside for loop not working properly repeating same values multiple times Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm wanting every `<tbody>` tag will be gone as object index like first `<tbody>`->1 and second `<tbody>`-> 2 then inside the `<tbody>` every `<tr>` will be another object and that will be store into the `<tbody>` object and last the last part every `<td>` should have object key ("eiin", "name") inside the `<tr>` object

I'm trying using for loop multiple times but the console.log showing me okay but first  object repeated 2 times.

**Html**

```
<section class="institute_list">
    <table class="table" border="1">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">EIIN</th>
                <th scope="col">Institute</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>000000</td>
                <td>Name</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>111111</td>
                <td>Name 2</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</section>
```

**Javascript & jQuery**

```
<script>
    var rows = '', the_row='', the_xrow={}, tr_values={}, xtd_obj={};
    tbodys = ($(".institute_list .table tbody").length);

    for( var x=0; tbodys > x; x++)  {
        rows = $('.institute_list .table tbody:nth-child('+(x+1)+') tr').length;
        the_row = '.institute_list .table tbody:nth-child('+(x+1)+') tr:nth-child(';

        for( var i=1; rows >= i; i++ ){
            tr_values = {
                'eiin'   : $(the_row+i+') td:first-child').text(),
                'name'   : $(the_row+i+') td:nth-child(2)').text()
            };

            the_xrow[i] = tr_values;
        }  
        xtd_obj[x] = the_xrow;
    }
    console.log(xtd_obj);
</script>
```

and i'm getting this output in console
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EAOgB.png)

Comment: This is wrong in so many ways. I don't have the time right now to write a full answer, but just as hints: a) You have the second `<tbody>` _inside_ the first because you never close it with `</tbody>` - b) You use `nth-child` where it doesn't make sense, for example the first `<tbody>` is actually the _second_ child of the `<table>` because the `<thead>` is the first child, you should better just put all the relevant elements into a variable and then call `.eq(0)`, `.eq(1)` etc. on it (or even simpler, use jQuery's `.each` to iterate over all selected elements instead of a for loop)

Comment: But the most important issue here is this: You have only _one_ object `the_xrow` object that you assign to _all_ bodies over and over again!

Comment: That's why you see duplicate data. You should create a new object with `= {}` in each loop. (Object values are assigned by reference, not by value!)

Comment: Thanks for your clarify. It's solved. The fixed code has given another answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try the code below. You can separate every `<tbody>`,`<tr>`,`<td>` tag as a loop then make them a array.

```js
var target = $(".institute_list > table");

var output = [];
$(target).find("tbody").each(function(i){
    output[i] = {};
    $(this).children().each(function(j){
        output[i][j] = {};
         $(this).children().each(function(k, td){
          if ( k == 0 ) {
           output[i][j]["eiin"] = $(td).text();
          } else if ( k == 1 ) {
           output[i][j]["name"] = $(td).text();
          } else {
           output[i][j][k] = $(td).text();
          }
        });
    });
});
console.log(output);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<section class="institute_list">
    <table class="table" border="1">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">EIIN</th>
                <th scope="col">Institute</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>000000</td>
                <td>Name</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>111111</td>
                <td>Name 2</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</section>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it's working exactly that I want

Answer (score 1):

First, you need a closing `</tbody>` tag around the first element. Second I think you might be running into a scoping problem. You are defining `the_xrow` and `tr_values` outside of the for loops instead of inside of the for loops.

```
<script>
    var xtd_obj={};
    var tbodys = ($(".institute_list .table tbody").length);

    for( var x=1; tbodys >= x; x++)  {
        var current_row = '.institute_list .table tbody:nth-child('+x+') tr';
        var rows = $(current_row).length;
        var the_row = current_row + ':nth-child(';
        var the_xrow = {};
        for( var i=1; rows >= i; i++ ){
            the_xrow[i] = {
                'eiin'   : $(the_row+i+') td:first-child').text(),
                'name'   : $(the_row+i+') td:nth-child(2)').text()
            };
        }  
        xtd_obj[x] = the_xrow;
    }
    console.log(xtd_obj);
</script>
```

Comment: Yes, I exactly meant that. That's are defined variables and objects

Comment: What do you want your output to look like?

Comment: sorry! there will be tr_values={} instead of get_row_values={}

Answer (score 0):

It's working for me

```
<script>
    var rows = '', the_row='', xtd_obj={};
    var tbodys = ($(".institute_list .table tbody").length)+1;

    for( var x=1; tbodys > x; x++)  {
        rows = $('.institute_list .table tbody:nth-child('+(x+1)+') tr').length;
        the_row = '.institute_list .table tbody:nth-child('+(x+1)+') tr:nth-child(';
        var the_xrow = {};
        for( var i=0; rows > i; i++ ){
            var tr_values = {
                'eiin'   : $(the_row+i+1+') td:first-child').text(),
                'name'   : $(the_row+i+1+') td:nth-child(2)').text()
            };

            the_xrow[i] = tr_values;
        }  
        xtd_obj[x] = the_xrow;
    }
    console.log(xtd_obj);
</script>
```

[Here's the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7DDoK.png)